# When Div Expands my screen does not activate a scroll bar

Tags: html, css, divider

As you can see, when the div expands I have no option to scroll down and I'm wondering how I would go about fixing this. Here is my css

```
<style>

 #cust_info {
  width: 300px;
  min-height:350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #66CCFF;
  padding: 20px; 
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40px;
  font-family: arial;
  }

   .more {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }

  a.showLink, a.hideLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #36f;
  padding-left: 8px;
  background: transparent url(down.gif) no-repeat left; }

  a.hideLink {
  background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left; }

  a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #36f; }
 </style>
```

I gave the div a min height so it would expand without text leaving the area, but when the div expands past the screen I lose most of the div.

Comment: It's because of the fixed position. You should avoid using fixed like that and instead use a layout using floated divs or absolute positioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove `position:fixed` from `#cust_info id`.

Removing that will automatically give a scroll in your page.

For keeping it left align, just give `float:left` to `#cust_info`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot, I will check this off when its possible